# Run arquillian test with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, junit, jboss-arquillian

I make my first steps with arquillian. I just setup a java-ee project (using wildfly ear archetype).
The pom delivers 2 profiles: "wildfly-arquillian-container-managed" (only runs if JBOSS_HOME is properly set) and "wildfly-arquillian-container-remote"

Both are running fine. But how to run them in Eclipse? I read [here](http://arquillian.org/guides/getting_started/) "and select Run As > JUnit Test " but this yields

```
DeployableContainer must be specified
```

But i also found ["Arquillian Eclips"](http://tools.jboss.org/features/arquillian.html). It should provide "add Arquillian support and "run as Arquillian JUnit test". I installed JBoss Tools in my Juno but can't find any "arquillian".

So how to run Arquillian test from within Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

The maven profiles activate a container adapter. When you run them the container adapter can start wildfly.

When you run your test in Eclipse you have to add this container adapter to your class path. When you then choose Run As > JUnit Test it will take this container adapter into account and run wildfly.

Comment: i don't want to fiddle with eclipse project settings. Meanwhile i found how to install arquillian-eclipse..

Comment: What went actually wrong the first time you installed it?

Comment: it is not installed by default. i think it's because its marked as "experimental"

Answer (score 0):

I found jboss-Tool's arquillian-eclipse:
Via help->install new software
Choose "http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/luna/" as update site. You'll found arquillian support in "JBoos Web and Java EE Development".
This will bring among other things "run as arquillian test". It will configure maven (pom) and will setup test run targets.

Answer (score 0):

The option which works in every IDE I know is to select the default Maven profile to run.

With Eclipse it's available from Project | Maven |
Select Maven Profiles. Choose the Arquillian Managed profile as an example.

Then, in arquillian.xml file configure the location where JBoss/WildFly is installed.
Source: [Running Arquillian from Eclipse](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/arquillian/running-arquillian-tests-from-eclipse)